# Email reply: should I strip (Re|Fw(d)?), or any word with a colon?

Tags: email, email-headers

I am writing a program that composes an email reply. The original email may be a reply already. How should I handle the subject?

I have seen the everything-before-the-colon method used. This could affect a situation `re[2]:`. If the colon method was used. The reply would become `Re:` and the other party's computer would lose count.

If not, the reply would become `Re: re[2]` Then the next reply could come through as `re[4]` as was intended.

But the colon method can be useful for cases where you say `Resending:` and the next reply would become `Re:`.

Do you have input on this? Is there a standard or common way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(With no context at all it's difficult to provide a concrete answer - you may want to provide more information in your question)*

Most decent [mail user agents (MUA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_user_agent) use the [`In-Reply-To:` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_headers#Message_header) to indicate message threading, without resorting to unsafe operations such as parsing the `Subject:` header. Most such clients also have a proper threading mode where unusual stuff such as `Re[2]:` is at best unnecessary. The [de facto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto) standard of using `Re:` is a good compromise between terseness and content, but with proper threading support it eventually comes down to aesthetics.

- Just use `Re:` in messages you create yourself - anything else is bound to lead to confusion. Make sure you properly generate the `In-Reply-To:` header for any reply messages.
- Please do not *remove* content from the `Subject:` header. You may refrain from adding to it when e.g. a proper `Re:` substring already exists, but if you are actually removing strings you are bound to get it wrong, leading to confusing situations.
- This is not a strictly technical issue - different people have different preferences. In a specific community, e.g. a mailing list, social automation (sic) will take care of any repeat offender that uses strange or confusing conventions.
- Trying to deal with this automatically is bound to cause more problems than it would solve. Such issues are also not the responsibility of the carrier - i.e. the mailing system. Keep your system simple and focus on *real* technical problems.

**EDIT:**

A common case of a broken client (or user - I have always been unclear on this) is the `Re:` avalanche case:

```
Subject: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: What about that thing we were talking about?
```

Tempting isn't it? A simple filter rule in the [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent), or a few lines of code in a replying MUA and the avalanche is replaced by a nice, *single* `Re:` automatically!

In my opinion, this is one case where the temptation should be resisted to:

- There is no guarantee that an MTA is the only path a specific message uses. For example, when some users reply to mailing list messages, they reply both to the mailing list and directly to the poster. Naturally, the poster will receive both messages, most probably by completely different paths.

  Do you know how confusing it can be to receive the same message with two different subject lines? Even a basic sort-by-subject would fail. In my opinion, even spam detection systems that add `[SPAM]`, `**SPAM**`, `$P@M` or whatever to the subject are pushing it.

  Can you imagine a library selectively changing the titles of their book copies according to some sort of local policy?
- Even if your MUA "fixes" the issue, everyone else will still be using the old subject, except for when replying to you. Moreover, you have just single-sidedly created what appears to be a new thread. Proper mail clients will still display the thread correctly, but the visual effect is confusing. After all, you *did* remove a highly distinctive feature of this thread from your reply post, didn't you?

  I actually remember a couple of fun threads where the `Re:` avalanche in their subject was part of a tongue-in-cheek discussion. Why would you want to miss on that?

Sure, people use broken clients. Or they are broken themselves. If anyone gets *really* out of line it can be handled individually. Just don't compound the problem and leave our `Subject:` headers alone. Please? Pretty please?

Comment: Concur, but still feel the need to mention misdirected localizations. Several products translated Re: into the user's language (sometimes differently, even in different versions of the same product) leading to ever-growing chains of Vs: AW: Sv: prefixes on Subject lines. An exhaustive catalog is probably impossible to collect, but if you can list a dozen or so, this static list will probably allow you to handle nearly all the real-world cases.

Comment: @tripleee: I still think that mangling the subject is not the way to go - see my edit.